# How to use volley to fetch bitmaps with custom params

Tags: android, android-volley

Has anyone used the Volley library?
I'm trying to fetch bitmaps through volley, but I don’t know how to add custom parameters to the request.

Here is my code:

```
 RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
 ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new BitmapLruCache(       BitmapLruCache.getDefaultLruCacheSize()));
 imageLoader.get(IMAGE_URL,ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_error));
```

Can anyone tell me how to add custom params with this call?

Answer (score 0):

Basically Volley provide two ways to request image

Example :

```
ImageRequest imgRequest = new ImageRequest(<URL>, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(response);
        }
    }, 0, 0, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.error);
        }
    });
mVolleyQueue.add(imgRequest);
```

ImageDownloader

//Initialising ImageDownloader

```
int max_cache_size = 1000000;
mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mVolleyQueue, new DiskBitmapCache(getCacheDir(),max_cache_size));
```

( or )
Memorycache is always faster than DiskCache. Check it our for yourself.
mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mVolleyQueue, new BitmapCache(max_cache_size));

```
mImageLoader.get(<URL>, 
        ImageLoader.getImageListener(mImageView, 
                    R.drawable.flickr, 
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert),
                    //You can optional specify width & height of the bitmap to be scaled down when the image is downloaded.
                    50,50);
```

NetworkImageView

```
mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(testUrlToDownloadImage1, mImageLoader);
```

If you want more control and options you can try UniversalImagerLoader

See more here : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

**Configuration**

All options in Configuration builder are optional. Use only those you really want to customize.
See default values for config options in Java docs for every option.

```
// DON'T COPY THIS CODE TO YOUR PROJECT! This is just example of ALL options using.
// See the sample project how to use ImageLoader correctly.
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context);
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        .memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800) // default = device screen dimensions
        .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, null)
        .taskExecutor(...)
        .taskExecutorForCachedImages(...)
        .threadPoolSize(3) // default
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1) // default
        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
        .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
        .memoryCacheSizePercentage(13) // default
        .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // default
        .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
        .diskCacheFileCount(100)
        .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()) // default
        .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(context)) // default
        .imageDecoder(new BaseImageDecoder()) // default
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()) // default
        .writeDebugLogs()
        .build();
```

**Display Options**

Display Options can be applied to every display task (ImageLoader.displayImage(...) call).

Note: If Display Options wasn't passed to ImageLoader.displayImage(...)method then default Display Options from configuration (ImageLoaderConfiguration.defaultDisplayImageOptions(...)) will be used.

```
// DON'T COPY THIS CODE TO YOUR PROJECT! This is just example of ALL options using.
// See the sample project how to use ImageLoader correctly.
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub) // resource or drawable
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty) // resource or drawable
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error) // resource or drawable
        .resetViewBeforeLoading(false)  // default
        .delayBeforeLoading(1000)
        .cacheInMemory(false) // default
        .cacheOnDisk(false) // default
        .preProcessor(...)
        .postProcessor(...)
        .extraForDownloader(...)
        .considerExifParams(false) // default
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2) // default
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) // default
        .decodingOptions(...)
        .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer()) // default
        .handler(new Handler()) // default
        .build();
```

you can use both in your project smoothly.